# Why Django raw query is not working

Tags: django

Good people,
I have installed djangoratings in my django project and i want to select records directly using raw sql from the djangoratings tables, i have followed the instruction given [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql) but nothing seems to work.

My code looks like this;

```
def InsertRecord():
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(" Select ip_address from djangoratings_vote where id=%d ",[3])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row   # row has None at this point
```

The function does not select the row, despite it exists in the table.
Am using , django 1.2.1, sqlite3

What am i not doing?

gath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only strings will work, so replace %d with %s and it should work

```
cursor.execute(" Select ip_address from djangoratings_vote where id=%s ",[3,])
```

Answer (score 1):

good people,

Sorry i saw where the mistake was,

On the sql string, the formating place holder should be **"%s"** and not **"%d"**

thanks